# Windows telnet + controlling local echo from remote

Tags: windows, ruby, telnet, echo

I have the same problem as [How to unsupress local echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098503/how-to-unsupress-local-echo) but none of the solutions in that thread are desirable.

Specifically, I'm using telnet for communication with a simply Ruby program that requires authentication to connect remotely. When the user is prompted for a password I want to suppress local echo, so I send the password prompt followed by IAC DONT ECHO, then send IAC DO ECHO after receiving a newline.

This method appears to work fine for most telnet clients, but when using windows 'telnet' (Windows XP SP2 version) I get back IAC WONT ECHO and IAC WILL ECHO respectively, but after the password prompt local echo is permanently disabled.

Does anyone know of a work around for this, or will I just have to avoid windows telnet?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I could be accused of Windows bashing if I say there are better 
alternatives to Windows telnet.

[Putty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) is a popular alternative.

Comment: That is true, and using windows telnet isn't necessary. I am still curious why it would do this however, since I've never experienced this problem connecting to public telnet servers with windows telnet before, which indicates to me that there's something that can be done programmatically to correct this problem.