# Using telnet under windows to test HTTP

Tags: http, telnet, windows-7-x64

I'm learning http, and trying to use telnet to send my own http requests.

In the command prompt, I entered:

```
telnet google.com 80
```

Result: 
The screen is cleared and I see a blinking cursor.
1. Why don't I see any indication that I'm connected?

Now, trying to type an http command (get index.html...)
I see the cursor moving to the right as I type, but I don't see the letters appear on the screen. Only blanks.
2. Why is that?

(Using windows7 64 bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why don't I see any indication that I'm connected?

The blinking cursor on a blank screen *is* the indication you are connected. Otherwise, you'll get an error describing why you couldn't connect.

> I see the cursor moving to the right as I type, but I don't see the letters appear on the screen.

[Use localecho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098503/how-to-unsupress-local-echo).

> an http command (get index.html...)

That is not a valid HTTP request, you should at least type something like this, followed by two <kbd>Enter</kbd>s:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
```

Look at the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) on how to construct an HTTP request and see some samples.

Comment: Thank you! The set localecho did the trick. 
Why on earth would anybody prefer not to see what he is typing? (i suspect that there is a reason...)

Comment: You're assuming a local echo is the only way to see what you're typing.  However, a server might provide a remote echo.  If you had both a local and a remote echo, you'd see two of every letter you typed.

Comment: I was responding to @shealtiel's comment, which was a question about local echo in a telnet client.